# One hundred students were questioned about their study habits

Tags: combinatorics

One hundred students were questioned about their study habits. Seventy
said they sometimes studied during the day, 55 said they sometimes studied
during the night, and 45 said they sometimes studied during the weekend. Also, 36 studied during the day and night, 24 during the day and at weekends,
17 during the night and at weekends, and 3 during the day, night,
and weekends. How many did not study at all?

I know the answer is 4, but I don't understand how to get there.

100 students, 70 day, 55 night, 36 both:

$$70 + 55 - 36 = 89$$

$100 - 89 = 11$ students may not study

45 weekends, 24 day, 17 night, 3 both:

$$24 + 17 - 3 = 38$$

$45 - 38 = 7$ students do not student at weekends

Since the answer is 4, I suppose that I have to do:

$$11- 7 = 4$$

I do not understand why? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: One thing that is already bothering me (I don't know the answer to your question yet): I draw a Venn diagram to get things clear, and what I don't get is that, if 36 students studied night and day, 3 studied during night, day and week-end, and 17 studied during nights and week-ends, then we should have 36+3+17=56 students who studied during the night, not 55.

Comment: And does the "solution" you give comes from a book or...? I don't really understand what you're doing.

Comment: I understand that from that 36, 3 of them studies in the weekend aand from that 17 is already counting the 3 that study both

Comment: The question is from the book : Modern algebra with applications question 2.15, it only says that the answer is 4

Comment: Finally got why it didn't work, thanks to jvdhooft. Hope you got it as well. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a Venn diagram to solve this problem:

[image]

First fill in the center part, where 3 students study during the day, at night and in the weekends. Since we know that 36 students study during the day and at night, we know that $36-3=33$ of these students did not study in the weekend. We can do the same for the 24 and 17 students to complete the inner part of the diagram. Then, since we know that 70 students studied during the day, we deduce that 13 students studied during the day only. We can do the same for the 55 and 45 students who studied at night and during the weekend, thus completing the Venn diagram. Since the diagram includes 96 students, 4 students did not study at all.